# How to bind Search bar contents in View to Controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a search bar with two radio buttons in my Index view of my Customer model in MVC5.  I want to pass the contents of the search bar, namely which radio button has been selected and what has been entered into the search bar, to my CustomersController.  The controller, however, is not "seeing" the names in the view.  What am I doing wrong?

Search bar code in Index view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CustomersController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search by:</b>@Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Company")<text> Company</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Last Name")<text>Last Name</text><br />
    @Html.TextBox("Search");<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Index ActionResult in CustomersController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (searchBy == "Company")
    {
        return View(db.Customers
          .Where(x => x.Company.Contains == Search || Search == null).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        return View(db.Customers.Where(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(Search)).ToList());
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you are using `get` so why there is no parameter for `Index` method? It should be `Index(string searchBy)`. From where you're getting `searchBy` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your razor view as below you don't need to apply your full controller name just pass **"Customers"**

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Customers", FormMethod.Get))
   {
      <b>Search by:</b>@Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Company")<text> Company</text>
      @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Last Name")<text>Last Name</text><br />
      @Html.TextBox("Search");<input type="submit" value="Search" />
   }
```

And you controller method as below pass two **parameters** like below

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchby,string Search)
    {

        if (searchby == "Company")
        {
            return View(db.Customers.Where(x => x.Company.Contains == Search || Search == null).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.Customers.Where(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(Search)).ToList());
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: I am still getting red squigglies under "Search".  Why?

Comment: have you passed two parameters ?? if yes than please make sure you spell correct both in parameter and where you have been used that parameter.

string searchby,
string Search

there are two parameters you have to pass as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: where you find red squigglies move your cursor there and press **Cntrl+Space** it will give you a hint what u have done wrong and how to correct..

Comment: Thank you so much!  You made my Christmas.  Merry Christmas!

Comment: It's completely my pleasure and yes **Merry Christmas** to you too